# Will I die from a 50-foot fall?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision, biophysics, free-fall

Sorry if I didn't ask this in the right place, but...

Will I die from a 50-foot fall? What are the chances of survival? I know this is more of a biology question or something, sorry :(

Comment: How much do you weight?

Comment: Please see [this article on Outdoors.SE](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8106/how-far-would-you-need-to-fall-for-it-to-be-fatal)

Comment: On what are you falling on to? Snow or concrete?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the fall that kills you.  Your chance of survival is 100%  :)

In regards to the suspected impact after the fall, you will need to expand on the parameters to your question.  Divers survive 50ft drops routinely.  The elderly are killed from 4 foot drops routinely.

I'm sure this wasn't the answer you were looking for, but I think the best answer is *it depends*...

Answer (score 1):

Well let's say you weigh 220 lbs. Which translates over to 100 kg. The fall is 50 ft, so about 15.24 meters. The running thing that most people say is that it takes about 5000 Newtons of force to break a human bone, but we know that, this varies. We also know that it is not how hard you hit something that necessarily kills you, it's energy from the impact, that sudden stop, that does most of its damage.

So let's math it out here, and just for the sake of humor let's assume it's a hard surface, say concrete:

Let's start with the basics:

$g = 9.8\frac{m}{s^2}$

$t_{impact} = \sqrt{\frac{2h}{9.8}}$

$v_{impact} = 2gh$

$E_{impact} = \frac{m}{2}v^2 = mgh$

So...

$t_{impact} = \sqrt{\frac{2(15.24)}{9.8}} = 1.76s$

$v_{impact} = \sqrt{2(9.8)(15.24)} = 17.28\frac{m}{s}$

$E_{impact} = mgh = (100)(9.8)(15.24) = 14,935.2 joules$ and let's say you bounce 1 meter after the hit, then you're looking at an impact force of $14935 N$

So overall result, depending on how you land you're looking at broken bones, organ trauma, probably some internal bleeding. It's been awhile since I've done these types of calculations, but I'm pretty sure these are the correct ones.

Comment: Thanks! My weight is 40 kg, which means I'll hit the ground at a slower speed, but I think it should kill you. Plus I'm falling on concrete.